# vlookup multiple values excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a lookup in excel with multiple values. I have two tables: one with the account name (column A) and state (column B) and second with the account name (column D) and state (column E). The goal is to fill out column B with the state from column E. How can I do this with a look up formula in excel?

I tried using this formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$10, SMALL(IF(A2=$D$2:$D$10, ROW($D$2:$D$10)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")`

```
AA          AA  CA
AA          AA  NY
AA          AA  MD
BB          BB  FL
BB          BB  NY
BB          CC  AZ
DD          CC  CO
DD          DD  CO
            DD  WA
```

Comment: I think you should [edit] in a clarification.  We can assume, but that's a bad road to travel down.  Do you want ALL matches?  i.e.: `AA` on line 1 gets `CA`, line 2 gets `NY` etc.?  Is there always a 1:1 count of A to B account names (exact counts of each instance)?

Comment: What do expect to return for your third BB? Since there are only two in your lookup table?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first match =INDEX($D$1:$E$9,MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$9,0),2). In this case you should make a new column and concatenate (=concatenate(D1," - ",F1)) two columns that will create a unique string which can be searched on. For example, address, phone number etc.